# Symfony and Jquery : $ is not defined

Tags: jquery, twig

With Symfony, I create a form and form template for my collection :

```
{% block _training_versions_entry_dates_widget %}
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var datesCount = {{ form|length }};

        $(function () {
            $('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
                ...
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

But I have this error : **Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined**

I load Jquery in my `base.html.twig` :

```
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

I think because my theme is called before Jquery, but I don't want to move jquery in my `<head>`. Can you help me ?

Comment: try to load jquery before your js code execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your js code must be called after jquery loading. So you can do something like this in your layout, add a block for the js code before the `</body>` tag:

**layout.html.twig**:

```
{% block javascripts_footer %}
    <script src="{{ asset('vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js') }}">            
{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, in your template, write your js in the `javascripts_footer` block, not in the `content` one:

```
{% block javascripts_footer %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
        $(document).ready(){
            var datesCount = {{ form|length }};           
            $(function () {
               $('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
                   ...
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to wrap your function inside `$(document).ready()` or `$(window).load()`
try this:

```
$(document).ready(){
    var datesCount = {{ form|length }};

    $(function () {
       $('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
           ...
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I have same error with `$(document).load(function() {` or `$(document).ready(function() {`

Answer (score 0):

Your inline JavaScript is executed before jQuery will load, assuming the block `_training_versions_entry_dates_widget` is a child of the block `body`.
Either move your inline JavaScript below the jQuery source or the other way around like you already described by putting it in the head.

You may want to set `{{ form|length }}` as a data attribute and grab it later by JavaScript. That way you don't need inline JavaScript.

```
$(function () {    
    var datesCount = $('#add-another-email').attr('data-form-length');
    $('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
        ...
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also wrap it into a pure JavaScript statement:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  var datesCount = {{ form|length }};

  $(function () {
     $('#add-another-email').click(function(e) {
       ...
     });
  });
}
```